# How to use ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator with a custom WebSocketHandler

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a custom WebSocket handler (for a custom sub-protocol), registered the usual way:

```
public class WSConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        webSocketHandlerRegistry
                .addHandler(new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(CustomProtocolHandler.class), endpointUrl);
    }
}
```

Inside `CustomProtocolHandler` all methods inherited from `WebSocketHandler` (e.g. `afterConnectionEstablished`,  `handleMessage` etc) receive `WebSocketSession` which is not thread-safe. The official tutorial says `ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator` can be used to prevent concurrent writes, but by the time my custom handler is hit it is already too late to wrap the session.

```
public class CustomProtocolHandler implements WebSocketHandler, SubProtocolCapable {

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        //This is not safe
        session.sendMessage(...);

        //And this this doesn't make sense
        new ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator(session).sendMessage(...);
    }
}
```

Now, I see that Spring's own `SubProtocolWebSocketHandler` (which, like mine, implements `WebSocketHandler` and `SubProtocolCapable`) does decorate the session internally, and I was hoping I'd be able to use it as the basis, but to create `SubProtocolWebSocketHandler` I need `MessageChannel` which comes from spring-messaging. I neither use Spring Messaging, nor have any clue how I would get a `MessageChannel`. Should I be implementing a custom one?

So, how is `ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator` intended to be used? I would expect a way to register session-wrapping logic with the `webSocketHandlerRegistry`, but nope. The only idea I have is to maintain yet another `ConcurrentHashMap` that maps the raw session (or its ID) to a wrapper, but that's horrible and the one thing I don't need is more state to manage and clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making my own version of `PerConnectionWebSocketHandler` that, like the original, maintains a session-to-handler map, but mine wraps the handler into a holder that also contains a decorated session for the handler to use.

The original `PerConnectionWebSocketHandler` looks like this:

```
public class PerConnectionWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler, BeanFactoryAware {

    private final Map<WebSocketSession, WebSocketHandler> handlers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    ...

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        WebSocketHandler handler = this.provider.getHandler();
        this.handlers.put(session, handler);
        handler.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }
}
```

And mine now looks like this:

```
public class CustomPerConnectionWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    private final Map<WebSocketSession, HandlerWrapper> handlers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    ...

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        WebSocketHandler handler = ...;
        //Here's a chance to decorate the session as needed
        WebSocketSession decoratedSession = new ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator(session, sendTimeLimit, sendBufferSizeLimit);
        HandlerWrapper wrapper = new HandlerWrapper(handler, decoratedSession);
        this.handlers.put(session, wrapper);
        wrapper.afterConnectionEstablished();
    }


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
         //Delegate all the calls in this fashion
         handlers.get(session).handleMessage(message);
    }

    ...

    private static class HandlerWrapper {

        private final WebSocketHandler handler;
        private final WebSocketSession session;

        HandlerWrapper(WebSocketHandler handler, WebSocketSession session) {
            this.handler = handler;
            this.session = session;
        }

        void afterConnectionEstablished() throws Exception {
            handler.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
        }

        void handleMessage(WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
            handler.handleMessage(session, message);
        }

        ... //Other delegating methods
    }
}
```